# Increment / decrement jQuery affecting wrong input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a bit new to JavaScript. I've tried to make some simple code to increment and decrement products in a shopping cart. Here is the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/spadez/q9umfz8a/1/

HTML

```
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>A</li>
      <li class="active">B</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<main>
  <nav>
    <form>
      <h2>
Per Day
      </h2>
      <input type="radio" name="qty" value="5">5
      <input type="radio" name="qty" value="6">6
      <h2>
Days
</h2>
      <input type="radio" name="days" value="1">1
      <input type="radio" name="days" value="3">3
      <input type="radio" name="days" value="5">5
      <h2>
      Items
      </h2>
      <label>Apple</label>
      <img src="">
      <input value="0" class="number">
      <button class="decrement">-</button>
      <button class="increment">+</button>
      <label>Lemon</label>
      <img src="">
      <input value="0" class="number">
      <button class="decrement">-</button>
      <button class="increment">+</button>
    </form>
  </nav>
</main>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".increment").click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    var $n = $(".number");
    $n.val(Number($n.val()) + 1);
  });
  $(".decrement").click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    var $n = $(".number");
    $n.val(Number($n.val()) - 1);
  });
});
```

How do I make it affect the input box which the buttons are next to? Furthermore, I'm aware this may be a poor way to approach this - how can I do this better?

Comment: __ID must be unique__

Comment: @RayonDabre Sorry you are correct - I edited it

Comment: @Jimmy Rayon meant the ID of the input field has to be unique. Why are you using JavaScript to solve this? Use HTML5, already built in. input type="number" with max/min and increment = automatic up/down

Comment: I would also suggest learning JavaScript before going into jQuery. jQuery is just a framework, if you don't understand the fundamentals behind that, then you're going to struggle asking the right questions

Comment: @zerohero I am a bit worried that this wouldn't work on older browsers

Comment: @Jimmy even jquery have stopped support for older browser. any browser out there today that has support from jquery/microsoft/google can run html5, even phones. which browsers are you wanting to target? because I can show you usage statistics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you have `event.preventDefault();` in your functions but you never actually set the event (so the default action is not actually being prevented), however this isn't even required; you can simple set the buttons to have the type "button" like so:

```
<button type="button" class="decrement">-</button>
<button type="button" class="increment">+</button>
```

If your would prefer to prevent the default action however, you simply need to set the event like so:

```
$(".increment").click(function(event) { 
    //function code 
});
```

Secondly, the selector `$('.number')` selector is ambiguous and results in both inputs being affected when the incrementation or decrementation buttons are press, a solution to this would be something like:

```
var $n = $(this).prevAll(".number:first");
```

This would result in only the first previous `$('.number')` being selected.

**Here is all the Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".increment").click(function() {
    var $n = $(this).prevAll(".number:first");
    $n.val(Number($n.val()) + 1);
  });

  $(".decrement").click(function() {
    var $n = $(this).prevAll(".number:first");
    $n.val(Number($n.val()) - 1);
  });

});
```

**Here is a working fiddle:**

https://jsfiddle.net/q9umfz8a/2/

Another option is using the HTML5 input type "number" which functions very similarily

```
<input type="number" value="0" class="number">
```

Answer (score 1):

> Use [`.prevAll`](http://api.jquery.com/prevall/) with `:first` to find the `previous-input-child` of the current element.

As mentioned by [*Johnny Kutnowski*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4050852/johnny-kutnowski) in comments, `.prevAll()` will get all preceding siblings of each element in the set of matched elements. Use `:first` to filter the selected elements.

Use `classes` instead of duplicate `id` attributes.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".increment").click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).prevAll('input:first').val(function() {
      return Number(this.value) + 1;
    });
  });
  $(".decrement").click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).prevAll('input:first').val(function() {
      return Number(this.value) + -1;
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.active {
  font-weight: underline;
}
label {
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 20px 0 8px 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>A</li>
      <li class="active">B</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<main>
  <nav>
    <form>
      <h2>
Per Day
      </h2>
      <input type="radio" name="qty" value="5">5
      <input type="radio" name="qty" value="6">6
      <h2>
Days
</h2>
      <input type="radio" name="days" value="1">1
      <input type="radio" name="days" value="3">3
      <input type="radio" name="days" value="5">5
      <h2>
      Items
      </h2>
      <label>Apple</label>
      <input value="0">
      <button class="decrement">-</button>
      <button class="increment">+</button>
      <label>Lemon</label>
      <input value="0">
      <button class="decrement">-</button>
      <button class="increment">+</button>
    </form>
  </nav>
</main>
```

### [**Fiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/wspxx9r9/10/)

Comment: The buttons for the "Lemon" input are incorrectly linked to the "Apple" input. This is caused by the `.prevAll()`, which chooses all of them.

Answer (score 1):

Change your variable to this and it will work

```
var $n = $(this).parent().find('.number');
```

You have to tell it to find the item you clicked within.
Working fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/spadez/q9umfz8a/1/